# (tortoise)svn reintegrate branch - missing file locally

Tags: svn, merge, branch, tree-conflict

I have an SVN repository (hosted @ googlecode); now the code is split up in 2 branches I worked on both seperately as they tackled slightly different things.

Now that I'm finished with both I am trying to reintegrate the side branch into the main trunk. This worked apart for a few things.
In the side branch I have (obviously) created new files. These files give apparently a "tree conflict" when using 'reintegrate branch' using tortoiseSVN. SVN (states) correctly "file is missing in local branch".

Now how do I actually "integrate" files correctly? So that the main trunk includes all changes (and additions) of the branch?

Comment: Show **exact full** output of `svn merge` and version of your SVN-client. Clean adding files in source **must not** produce tree conflict (at least in *rather fresh* Subversion)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Too long for comment, sorry</sup>

I can't catch your case, because (for extremely degenerated test)

```
>svn log -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2014-06-30 00:10:03 +0600 (Пн, 30 июн 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/F1/B.txt
   A /branches/F1/C.txt

Added B.txt + C.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2014-06-30 00:08:26 +0600 (Пн, 30 июн 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/F1 (from /trunk:2)

Branching trunk into F1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2014-06-30 00:07:09 +0600 (Пн, 30 июн 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/A.txt

Initial data
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2014-06-30 00:05:33 +0600 (Пн, 30 июн 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches
   A /tags
   A /trunk

Imported folder structure
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

merging F1 into trunk **must not** and **does not** produce unexpected tree conficts

```
trunk>svn merge file:///Z:/Repo/branches/F1 . --dry-run
--- Merging r3 through r4 into '.':
A    B.txt
A    C.txt
```

for

```
>svn --version
svn, version 1.8.9 (r1591380)
   compiled May  5 2014, 22:12:10 on x86-microsoft-windows
```

and must be the same even for SVN 1.6+

Comment: Well I get simply this: "The large merge operation tried to modify file xyz; but the file is missing locally" - actually in retrospect I did indeed modify it in branch A, had to rename it. (But as catia doesn't really understand svn this was a delete + add in the svn log)

Comment: @paul23 - show ull log of all actions, if (as) my reconstruction is wrong